# Fiona reading data

Tags: geopandas, fiona

I have problems concerning reading data using geopandas , but it seems the error is due to fiona according to this [post](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/227) I tried to reinstall fiona to 1.1.6 version, but still it does not work..

import fiona
    with fiona.open('taz.shp') as src:
        for feature in src:
            print feature

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-b70513efc12b> in <module>()
      1 import fiona
      2 with fiona.open('taz.shp') as src:
----> 3     for feature in src:
      4         print feature

fiona/ogrext.pyx in fiona.ogrext.Iterator.__next__ (fiona/ogrext.c:17244)()

fiona/ogrext.pyx in fiona.ogrext.FeatureBuilder.build (fiona/ogrext.c:3254)()

IndexError: list index out of range
```

But when I write other similar script, it seems to work

```
c = fiona.open('taz.shp', 'r')
print c
<open Collection 'taz.shp:taz', mode 'r' at 0x106f51dd0>
```

Comment: My lib version, GDAL: 1.11.0, Fiona: 1.1.6,geopandas (0.1.0.dev-bdfc7fb)

Comment: And actually it works well for some file, but does not work for others.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through the same frustration as you until I made it finally working. The following packages work stable together:

```
GDAL: 1.11.2
Fiona: 1.6.0
Geopandas: 0.1.0.dev-
```

For detailed explanation on how to install it check out my other post on this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37634515/5853731