# Issues installing Geopandas on windows

Tags: geopandas

Is there a tutorial (step by step) to install geopandas on a windows pc? or which way works better?

I have tried the solutions in the documentation using anaconda but I ended up receiving errors (even creating an environment as recommended). I even tried installing what are called wheels for the different associated packages as suggested in another similar question. For someone new like me into python I was looking for something easy to follow to install, or there is not such thing when installing this package

Here the documentation:
https://geopandas.org/install.html

Comment: Which similar question ?

Comment: I was referring to another question like mine here in stackoverlfow with the title: Geopandas can install in anaconda. There I saw the suggestion for installing the different required packages (fiona, etc.) in a wheel format.

Comment: What is your python version ? Are you okay with not using Anaconda ?

Comment: I have the 3.7.6 version. I am ok with not using Anaconda

Comment: Python 3.7.6 32bit or 64bit ?

Answer (score 4):

After manually downloading the WHL files (whose names are listed below) from [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) onto a unique folder, open a command Prompt and type <sub>***Illustrated on Python3.7 64bit***</sub>

```
cd C:\path\to\the\folder\that\contains\the\WHL\files
pip3.7 install GDAL-3.0.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl && setx GDAL_VERSION "3.0.4"
pip3.7 install Fiona-1.8.13-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
pip3.7 install geopandas-0.7.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

*(tested)*

---

Another example
<sub>***Illustrated on Python3.8 32bit***</sub>

```
cd C:\path\to\the\folder\that\contains\the\WHL\files
pip3.8 install GDAL-3.0.4-cp38-cp38-win32.whl && setx GDAL_VERSION "3.0.4"
pip3.8 install Fiona-1.8.13-cp38-cp38-win32.whl
pip3.8 install geopandas-0.7.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try (and it is 64 bit)

Comment: Hello. I am working on it, just one questions: what does the && setx GDAL_VERSION "3.0.4" that you add at the end of the GDAL whl means? Just to be sure, this means that I have to type this in the command prompt?

Comment: should I have python added to windows path first?or it does not matter?

Comment: I received the following error: C:\Program Files\geopandas>pip install GDAL-3.0.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl && setx GDAL_VERSION "3.0.4"
ERROR: GDAL-3.0.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: I upgraded pip and when trying again I get this: (probably I am doing something wrong in the first place) C:\>cd C:\Program Files\geopandas

C:\Program Files\geopandas>pip3.7 install GDAL-3.0.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl && setx GDAL_VERSION "3.0.4"
'pip3.7' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files\geopandas>pip install GDAL-3.0.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl && setx GDAL_VERSION "3.0.4"
ERROR: GDAL-3.0.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform. I created a folder and put there the downloaded wheels

Comment: @Pierre what does `python ––version` return (when typed in the command prompt) ?

Comment: You either do not have python3.7.x or not the 64bit version.

Comment: Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 22:45:29) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information. But if I ask for conda list it gives me a 3.7.6 version (I have more than one python

Comment: I did that and it worked!! Now, two kind of questions: Do I have to do something else to be able to use geopandas in jupyter? I typed conda list in the anaconda promt and I do not see packages there. Or I am missing another step in the process?

Comment: I understand. This is what I got with that command ( cut the list  because of the limit of words: (base) C:\WINDOWS\system32> conda install contextily --channel
usage: conda-script.py install [-h] [--revision REVISION]
                               [-n ENVIRONMENT | -p PATH] [-c CHANNEL]
                     
conda-script.py install: error: argument -c/--channel: expected one argument

Comment: @Pierre my bad, first type `conda config --add channels conda-forge` and then retry `conda install contextily --channel conda-forge`.

Comment: Hi. it did not work. Anyway, thank you very much @keepAlive I do not want you to waist more of your time

Comment: @Pierre Pas de problème. Note however that having multiple python configurations may generate problems sooner or later. It is not that trivial to deal with parallelconfigs like that, and I would recommend you to keep only one of them. Actually, I am 85% sure that it is the cause of the issues you are facing with conda. Since it looks like you want to keep conda, you should remove python38, and retry `conda config --add channels conda-forge` and/or `conda install contextily --channel conda-forge`.

Comment: @Pierre this is an old post, but I install geopandas directly in a Colab notebook (assume it's the same for Jupyter) by adding `!pip install geopandas` into the first cell of the notebook, then running it.