# How to install python geopandas properly?

Tags: python, pandas, installation, pip, geopandas

I am trying to install geopandas. So, I downloaded all the required dependencies first(GDAL, pyproj, fiona, shapely). I was able to install GDAL and shapely using **pip** without any issue but for fiona and pyproj I am getting these following error,

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement certifi (from pyproj) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for certifi
```

Any reason why I would be getting these error? I have python version 3.10 and windows 10, so for all those dependencies I downloaded python 310 version.

Format of installing: `pip install pyproj-3.3.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl`

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: can you use conda? there's a reason the top half of the ["installing geopandas"](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started/install.html) guide is devoted to installing using conda. managing non-python geospatial dependencies manually is the worst.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to successfully install pyproj and geopandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34427788/how-to-successfully-install-pyproj-and-geopandas)

Comment: I tried using conda but it gives me http error. surprising thing is, using pip I was able to install gdal and shapely but not fiona and pyproj.

Comment: Highly recommend using conda, if possible. what http error does it give?

Comment: CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -  I am thinking this error is internal network related. Firewall blocking the connection.

Comment: I would try to figure out why conda isn't working - it's a much better long term fix!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue. Conda works fine, but with pip you usually hit compiler issues.

Here's the steps I took:

1. Download GDAL, Fiona, and shapely pre-compiled libraries from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/). Use Ctrl+F to find them, download the wheels to your code directory (or use pipwheel to install with @ ). Make sure you use the correct Python version and 32/64 bit versions.
2. Install shapely, Fiona, GDAL with pip if not using pipweel
3. pip install munch, folium, pygeos, geopandas

This should get you up and running. I advise you to first create a virtual environment in which you install the packages!

Comment: Yes, I used the same method as you mentioned but never heard of pipweel. It worked for GDAL & Shapely but the same method failed to install Fiona and pyproj.