# Geopandas not installing

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, geopandas

I am trying to install geopandas package in my system

When I am importing in my code, I got the below error message.

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_1412/3841419929.py in <module>
----> 1 import geopandas as gpd

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopandas'
```

Comment: Did you try to install it using `pip install geopandas`? See an introductioin [here](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started/install.html).

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to stack overflow! Installing geopandas can be tricky, and I'd actually recommend using conda. Conda is better than pip at installing complex multi-language dependencies such as PROJ, which is required by geopandas, which is why [conda is the recommended installation method in the geopandas docs](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started/install.html#installing-with-anaconda-conda). See this guide to installing and using conda: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to successfully install pyproj and geopandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34427788/how-to-successfully-install-pyproj-and-geopandas)